# How to add a tags-field to an entry form?

Tags: tags, form

I use the following entry form (front-end): https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entry-form

How can I add a tags-field to this entry form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to add inputs to the form based on your Tags field handle, with values set to the tag IDs that should be selected.

Here’s a very simple example – it creates a big checkbox list of all the existing tags:

```
<div id="tags">
    {% for tag in craft.tags.group('myTagsGroup').limit(null) %}
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="fields[myTagsField][]" value="{{ tag.id }}">
            {{ tag.name }}
        </label>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Note that it is not possible to create new tags directly from a Tags field. If you want users to also be able to create new tags from your form, that will require a little Javascript.

```
<a id="new-tag">+ New tag</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#new-tag').click(function()
    {
        var name = prompt('What’s the new tag name?');

        if (!name) return;

        var data = {
            groupId: 1,
            name: name
        };

        $.post('/actions/tags/createTag', data, function(response)
        {
            if (response.success)
            {
                $('<label>' +
                      '<input type="checkbox" name="fields[myTagsField][]" value="'+response.id+'" checked="checked"/> ' +
                    name +
                  '</label>').appendTo($('#tags'));
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Unable to create that tag.');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Make sure to set the correct `groupId` in that `data` object. You can find your tag group’s ID by looking at the URL when editing the group’s settings within Craft’s CP.