# Front-end form, creating a tag

Tags: form, entry, tags

Similar to the question asked here:
[How to add a tags-field to an entry form?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/how-to-add-a-tags-field-to-an-entry-form)

I am trying to create an entry form that can create tags. I'm using http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/ for the select element.

I am currently able to submit the form with existing tags but when trying to create a new tag using

```
$.post('/tags/createTag', data, function(response) {
    if (response.success) {
        alert('Success')
    } else {
        alert('Unable to create that tag.');
    }
});
```

I get `http://talkbox.es:8888/index.php/tags/createTag 404 (Not Found)`

Let me know if you guys need any more information, I'll gladly get it for you! Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not targeting the action URL. When accessing a Craft controller, you'll need to use the `actionTrigger` in your URL:

Your current URL:

```
http://talkbox.es:8888/index.php/tags/createTag
```

Should be updated to:

```
http://talkbox.es:8888/index.php/actions/tags/createTag
```

The [actionTrigger is configurable](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#actionTrigger) so if you plan to reuse your code on multiple sites, you won't want to hard code that value. In twig, you can output that value using the `craft.config` variable:

```
{{ craft.config.actionTrigger }}
```

Comment: I had tried with /actions/ in the url before but i still get `index.php/actions/tags/createTag 400 (Bad Request)` is there something i'm missing in my config file?

Comment: @MaximSiebert what was the cause of the Bad Request error? I am experiencing the same in a Craft 3 project